# How can I switch between images depending on array values

Tags: php, mysql

I have locally two images: 
/images/green_arrow_up.png
/images/red_arrow_down.png.
In my database I have a record and I fetch a number in this case.

```
   ["data"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(15) {
            [14]=>
            string(8) "+1.22%"
          }
        }
      }
```

I fetch the data like this

```
<div class="stats-item"><?php echo number_format((float)@$data->data[0][0][14], 2, '.', ''); ?>% </div>
```

Depending on the array from which i fetch the data the result can be +1.22% or -1.22% for example.
I want if the result is positive (1.22%) to display the green_arrow_up before the number. And if the result is negative (-1.22%) I want to display the red_arrow_down.

Comment: use if condition to check what value you have and make your decision...

Comment: can you give me an example for this specific case? I fail to succesfully do that.

Comment: where you need to put the images..

Comment: I make a post, just use the `$image` variable where you need your image.

Comment: I need to put the image right before the number in <div class="stats-item"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
   if ( number_format( (float) @$data->data[0][0][14], 2, '.', '' ) > 0 ) {
     echo "<img src='green_arrow.jpg'/>";
   }
   else {
     echo "<img src='red_arrow.jpg'/>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a simple condition you can detect which image to use. Here the `$image` variable stores the images link depending on the value.

```
$num = number_format((float)@$data->data[0][0][14], 2, '.', '');
if($num >= 0) $image = '/images/green_arrow_up.png';
else $image = '/images/red_arrow_down.png';
```